# How to type Tab character on any Android tablet?

Tags: special-chars

I failed to type a tabulation character as found in standard ASCII on a Galaxy Tab.

My first solution was to use f-droid store to install https://f-droid.org/de/packages/juloo.keyboard2/ and then do the obvious swipe on the right key.

However I want to be able to type it without having to swipe on a key.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Hackers' Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard).

You can get many apps just by searching "Programming keyboards" on Google play.

Comment: Unfortunately Hackers keyboard is not available for Galaxy Tab a 6 which I am using...